# Having problems with files in a netbeans package not finding a .txt file

Tags: java, netbeans, filenotfoundexception

So here is my constructor for a library class

```
          package OOD_PROJECT_PACKAGE;

import java.awt.Event;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;


 public class Library {
 private ArrayList<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
private ArrayList<Member> members = new ArrayList<Member>();
 private DefaultListModel mod1;
 //private DefaultListModel mod2;
private int nextValidId;
public Library(){
try {
    String fileName = "id.txt";
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    nextValidId = in.nextInt();

}
catch (FileNotFoundException e){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File not found");
//this wont happen,file will always be there

       }}
```

And i have a id.txt file in the source files.Yet it does not seem to be finding it and an expection occurs.I presume this has something to do with the fact the .txt does not have any form of package OOD_PROJECT_PACKAGE,so my library class cant see it.

How do i fix this?Thanks

Comment: Try to add `System.out.println((new File(fileName)).getAbsolutePath());` and it should help you understand your problem.

Comment: Thanks.I tried that and got H:\netbeans\OOD_PROJECT\id.txt.But when i try put that into filename variable i get an error of "illegal escape character"

Comment: try using `/` instead of ``\``

Comment: That got rid of the string error but with my updated code as such still cannot find the file       String  fileName = "H:/netbeans/OOD_PROJECT/id.txt";
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        nextValidId = in.nextInt(); Still

Comment: is your file `id.txt` located in `H:/netbeans/OOD_PROJECT/` ? Your question says it is in your source folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your project folder is H:/netbeans/OOD_PROJECT/ then you should put the id.txt in that folder, not H:/netbeans/OOD_PROJECT/src/.

In case you're planning on using the absolute path then the string should be: "H://netbeans//OOD_PROJECT//" or "H:\netbeans\OOD_PROJECT\" (I normally don't pay attention to whether I used \ or / but both seems to work for me).

Comment: It worked with String  fileName = "H:/netbeans/OOD_PROJECT/id.txt";  Any idea how to use it relatively?Because obviously when i hand this assignment up to be marked the file will not be in that location

Comment: Can you post the id.txt file too. I'll try to run it. Normally putting the text file in the project folder will do the job.

Comment: It just contains a single line that says 100

Comment: I just tried it and if the text file is in the OOD_PROJECT folder then all you need is "id.txt". 
When you submit the assignment, are you supposed to submit the project folder or just the source code and the text file? If code and text file only then you should try compiling using command console, putting the .java file and the text file in the same folder.

Comment: You are correct it works with just id.txt.I am submitting the project folder so it should be grand.Thanks alot:)

Comment: This might sound unsincere but can you help me with my reputation? I'm trying to comment on a question to ask the poster something but I need 50 reputations in order to do that. Thanks.

Comment: Congrats on reaching 50 rep.  :)

Comment: Thank you so much :D It sure feels weird asking questions in the answer section